# Unable to see the error message of the exception, when printed (e.Message) it's printing only the error code (like 404 or 400) but not message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, httpclient

```
// HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task APITest()
{
  // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(****************);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
     // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

     Debug.Log(responseBody);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     Debug.Log("\nException Caught!");  
     Debug.Log("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
```

it's printing only the error code (like 404 or 400) but not the error message.

But the error message is printed when checked in **postman** along with the error code.

Any insights, will help.

Comment: What is the exact output of your code and what are you expecting? Maybe show a picture of the expected output in postman.

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog with very good example: http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/07/getting-web-api-exception-details-from-a-httpresponsemessage/

also try getting the message from **response** 's properties, not from the exception.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString() ` will either print `True` or `False`...

Answer (score 0):

In general when working with Unity you don't want to have a `Main` method! Unity already provides the application framework and lifecycle!

Then also in general in Unity you don't want to use `Console.Write` but rather [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html)!

In your specific case [`Debug.LogException`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogException.html) so simply do

```
Debug.LogException(e);
```

which will log the entire exception including stack trace and everything to the console / the log file.

---

And finally you would rather use [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) instead.

Comment: It's a mistake from my side. I just copied that sample code from the microsoft website. I forgot about the Debug.Log. Thxs for it though.

Comment: @MohanReddy have you read the rest of the answer? ^^ your example still makes little sense in a Unity context .. you don't want a `Main` method .. and I told you to rather use `Debug.LogException` in order to get the full message and stacktrace. Then I also told you you rather want to use `UnityWebRequest` and in the example in the link you can see a full example including how to print out all relevant information in case of errors ;)